# Create .shp vector grid in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, vector-grid

I need to create vector grid 1km x 1km, but I can't figure out what parameters I should set. When I set some value, for example 1000.0, it creates grid with cells with 1000.0 x 1000.0 map degrees instead of meters.

How can I set x - spacing and y - spacing in meters?

Answer (score 4):

QGIS takes the map units for the processing tools from its project coordinate reference. You can change it for new projects in the options settings at "CRS". Or in the lower right corner of your main window where "EPSG:" is written, you can set the on the fly projetion that should be used for display and calculations.

To use meters you need a according projection based on meters (for example UTM). But you need to find the suitable coordinate system for the region you want to use the data.

Or you can calculate the decimal-degree-value for 1000m and use this for the input. But the length of one degree differs depending on the position on the earth. So it will not be accurate. Some rough explantion is given on this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees).